# Remove one row from gridlayout

Tags: android, row, grid-layout, android-gridlayout

I'm using a GridLayout with 5 coloums and multiple (not a fix value) rows. It is possible to add more rows with values to the grid by a add button (the values are hardcoded in hashmap for now).
In each row there is a delete button in the first cell.
Now I want to implement, that if you hit the delete button, the complete row should be deleted but also other rows should stay.
Any proposals how to do this?

Comment: Are you searching for something like this? https://android--code.blogspot.de/2015/08/android-gridview-add-item.html

Comment: Adding is not the problem, thats already implemented. Removing a row from the gridlayout is the problem

Comment: For me it seems to be not really the right tools to build what you want. If you just control the rows, why you're not using a simple list for your dataset and e.g. a RecyclerView, that would make things way simpler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could remove the specific dataset from your HashMap (or use another map in the adapter for the dymanic content) and then call:

```
grid.setRowCount(grid.getRowCount() - 1);
grid.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

That should remove the specific row.

Comment: This sounds like a good idea, but this would just delete the last element in the gridlayot, correct?. It should be possible to delete items somewhere in the middle

Comment: You just have to remove the correct data from your dataset. So if you had a list with your data in your adapter and row 3 should be deleted, then remove the 3rd item of your list and call `notifyDataSetChanged()`

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to explain without having your implementation, but I'll try. So suppose we have our `Activity/Fragment` with a `RecyclerView`. We have our `Adapter` who holds a `List/Map/Anything` with your elements in it. What we need is the delete button and it's click listener i guess. When you click the button you call a method in your adapter from the Activity/Fragment, which iterates your `List/Map/Anything` removing the items. The method then calls `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the Adapter again, and the grid should update correctly.